# How do you extend an abstract class in javascript and annotate for closure compiler but without closure library?

Tags: javascript, annotations, abstract-class, google-closure-compiler

Say I have an abstract class

```
/**@constructor
 * @abstract*/
function AbsFoo(){}

/**@return {number}
 * @param {number} a
 * @param {number} b */
AbsFoo.prototype.aPlusB = function(a,b){
    return a + b
};

/**@abstract
 * @return {number}
 * @param {number} c
 * @param {number} d */
AbsFoo.prototype.cMinusD = function(c,d){}; //extending class need to implement.
```

and i want to extend this class, normally, I would do something like

```
/**@constructor
 * @extends {AbsFoo} */
function Foo(){
    AbsFoo.apply(this);
}

Foo.prototype = new AbsFoo();
Foo.prototype.constructor = Foo;

Foo.prototype.doSomething = function(c,d){
    return c - d;
};
```

But closure compiler says

```
JSC_INSTANTIATE_ABSTRACT_CLASS: cannot instantiate abstract class
```

refering to the line `Foo.prototype = new AbsFoo();`

So how would I do this in a way that would keep the prototype inheritance, and the ability to use `instanceof` all the way up the class chain, but also make the compiler happy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `goog.inherits` in this situation.  Since you don't want to use closure library you could copy just `goog.inherits` from
[closure-library/closure/goog/base.js](https://github.com/google/closure-library/blob/master/closure/goog/base.js). Maybe give it the name `googInherits`. The code is then something like this:

```
/**@constructor
 * @extends {AbsFoo}
 */
Foo = function(){
    AbsFoo.apply(this);
}
googInherits(Foo, AbsFoo);

/** @inheritDoc */
Foo.prototype.cMinusD = function(c,d){
    return c - d;
};
```

Comment: If you look at the code for goog.inherits, I am already doing most of what that function does.

Comment: actually..... this works. I mean i did it a little different, but it's essentially the same. But it only seems to work because the goog.inherits function creates a new class, an abstract class that is like a bridge between the parent and child class.  The bridge class is an abstract class, but not annotated as such, so the compiler doesn't give the warning when creating an instance for the child prototype.... ....I feel like maybe the @abstract annotation is not yet in a stable state. I am pretty sure it is fairly new... whatever, thanks for the answer!

Comment: You are correct that Closure Compiler has recently upgraded its treatement of abstract classes. In my experience it is more consistent about finding problems with using abstract classes, which is what you ran into.